# Unable to retrieve list buckets: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied IBM COS from Watson Studio

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, websphere

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.  I have a feeling it is probably something to do with the credentials I am using, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am very new to Python and although I understand Object stores from an 'create bucket' level, I am struggling to get a grasp in the access from a programming interface.

Ideally I would like to have different credentials for different tasks, so an 'Admin' for all bucket operations down to a specific user for specific bucket operations.

I have tested a few things, such as the CRN from the CLI and I can list the buckets, but I login with my IBM credentials, so I suspect this is picking up those credentials when I run :

```
 Ibmcloud cos list-buckets
```

I have tried to use API keys from the Storage resource list.

So from the documentation I am trying the following commands:

```
COS_ENDPOINT="https://s3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"
COS_API_KEY_ID = "............................................"
COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.eu-gb.bluemix.net/oidc/token"
COS_RESOURCE_CRN = "the last part from the CRN string"

# Create resource.  In an ideal world, cos_m will be the big boss and I could use other
# users like cos_r or cos_a for specific bucket tasks

cos_m = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
    ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
    ibm_service_instance_id=COS_RESOURCE_CRN,
    ibm_auth_endpoint=COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
    config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
    endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT)

def get_buckets():
    print("Retrieving list of buckets")
    try:
        buckets = cos_r.buckets.all()
        for bucket in buckets:
            print("Bucket Name: {0}".format(bucket.name))
    except ClientError as be:
        print("CLIENT ERROR: {0}\n".format(be))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to retrieve list buckets: {0}".format(e))

get_buckets()


Returns the error:

Retrieving list of buckets
Unable to retrieve list buckets: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

I have also tried a set of credentials that work on a specific bucket, but I don't think those credentials have the ability to do operations such as list-buckets.

I hope this makes sense and thanks for taking a look.
```

Comment: Have you looked into IAM policies for that key? Was the key created with the right privileges for that service?

Comment: I will check again.  I ticked every box for manager, editor,... but I could have missed something in the setup.

Comment: iam_role_crn value  crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Manager
key iam_serviceid_crn value  crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/85985f27c

Comment: I added the Manager tole to the apikey, which should be able to list the bucket I hope

Comment: Hey mate, I know it is a quiet old question but I just had the same issue which I managed to solve.  You mention this: COS_RESOURCE_CRN = "the last part from the CRN string"
Instead of using the last part of the CRN String, go to service credentials on ibm cloud, click on copy  and you will have a json with a key of "resource_instance_id". copy that to  COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT and it will work.